# The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found. - Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.2, azure-webapps

I have an app running in **Azure App Service on Linux** and decided to upgrade the app from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 2.2. It is modeled after a `.NET Core 2.2` `dotnet new angular` template.

My app builds in Azure DevOps using the `Azure Web App for ASP.NET` template and its defaults plus the following updates to the `Azure App Service Deploy` task:

---

**App Service type**: Azure Web App for Linux

**Runtime Stack**: .NET Core 2.2

**Startup command**: dotnet MyAppName.dll

---

This task deploys the app successfully and I confirm the deployed contents through FTP.

Starting and navigating to the app shows this page:

[image]

Locally, my app runs successfully in Debug and Release modes in Visual Studio 2017. It will also work if I host the contents of a `dotnet publish -c Release` command locally.

I enabled logs using Monitoring > Diagnostics logs in the Azure portal and found this message in the file `2019_02_14_RD00155D99205C_default_docker.log`:

```
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377625884Z   _____                               
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377672685Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377679386Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377684186Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377688886Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377693986Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377698686Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377703186Z 
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377707486Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377711986Z Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
2019-02-14T19:52:29.377716587Z 
2019-02-14T19:52:29.956004709Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2019-02-14T19:52:30.234443169Z The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
2019-02-14T19:52:30.234492570Z   - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
2019-02-14T19:52:30.234498570Z       /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
2019-02-14T19:52:30.234615073Z   - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.2.0'.
```

I have not found any other clues. Does this imply that the default image Azure provides is not correct when setting Runtime Stack to .NET Core 2.2?

---

**Update**
Found [this link](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/151#issue-393674686) which mentions that 2.2 on Linux is being "rolled out" as of 02/12/2019. Perhaps this means that a correct image is not deployed yet where my App Service is located (US East). Assuming that is what is going on, adding a new non-working 2.2 option to the Azure Portal and Azure DevOps UI is a poor user experience.

Comment: I haven't deployed on linux yet but looks like 2.2 is not yet there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat The author of your link probably needs to update the page. It is available as an option in the Azure portal and as a deploy option in Azure DevOps for Linux apps. https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/151#issue-393674686

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 for the Linux variation of App Service has started deployment as of 02/12/2019. Estimated completion of the rollout is Friday 02/22/2019.

Comment: Try to login onto app service via console and do dotnet --list-runtimes

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I've tried using the console in the Azure Portal but it always errors out on connecting, even if I remove the startup `dotnet` command for the Docker image. But I am able to connect to my other Linux apps running on .NET Core 2.1 images via console. It could just be Microsoft added the 2.2 option too early, and an incorrect Docker image is associated with the 2.2 choice they added.

Comment: Hit a similar issue with azure DevOps build agents not yet being on later versions, I guess they allow for these because you may be using your own agents or deploying to non-azure destinations that could be up to date. Would be good if there was intelligence in DevOps that reported this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested again today and am able to deploy a .NET Core 2.2 Linux app. Most likely this started working February 26, 2018, judging by the latest edit on this [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/151#issue-393674686).